# Where to find function definitions for Corel Draw X6?

Tags: corel-draw

Is there, and if so, could somebody please point me to, an online resource for the Corel Draw Object Model? Something similar to the Object Browser within Corel Draw, that contains a complete listing of all objects, object members, member function definitions, etc..

Answer (score 0):

It is under Tools > Object Manager  and a pop-up to right hand beside the color shades[image]

Comment: Sorry. I may have not explained myself correctly. I am looking for a web page that details all the "objects" in the CorelDRAW object model. By "objects" here I am talking about a data structure used in Object Oriented Programming. This is for creating custom scripts using the Visual Basic for Applications Editor, or Macro Editor included in CorelDRAW. I would like a resource, similar to what you can find on MSDN when programming for the Windows API.

Comment: u mean u need macros

Comment: No.. I want the API details basically. The Application Programming Interface. If you go into the Macro Editor and press F2 you will see the Object Browser. I am looking for an online version of that. I only have CorelDRAW on my work PC and I'd like to be able to browse what is known as the CorelDRAW Object Model online.

Comment: Just go to the C:\Program Files (x86)\Corel\Corel Graphics 12\Programs
and search for 
PDFs: dvba_pg.pdf you will get all the information in that pdf page21 chapter 4

Comment: It's ok. I posted on Stack Overflow and somebody pointed me in the right direction. In case you are curious, this is what I am talking about https://community.coreldraw.com/sdk/api/draw/18